# Convert plane from ax+by+c=z form to ax+by+cz+d=0 form

Tags: plane-geometry

How to I convert a plane from the  ax+by+c=z form to ax+by+cz+d=0 form?

Comment: Take all the terms onto the same side of the equation?

Comment: What do you think? If you assumed everything was nice and simple and worked the way you expected it to do, how would you do it?

Comment: $ax+by+(-1)\cdot z+c=0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subtract $z$ from both sides. You'll get $$ax+by-z+c=0$$

Comment: I tried to visualize a b c d terms as a plane. While the normal looks correct, the plane doesn't lie on the points

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. What are you asking?